# Rewrite the markup of panels page title

Tags: theming, panels

I'm trying to rewrite the output of the title of a panels page. I would like to add a class, for example. Actually, if I understand well, panels takes the layout from `page.tpl.php` then from the selected layout for its contents.
I tried to use `taxonomy-term.tpl.php` (I'm using the taxonomy page override by panels) but it doesn't work. Still, panels takes header, navbar and title styles from `page.tpl.php`.
Is there a way to avoid this? Is there a way to add a class or an id to the title element of a panels page?

Edit:
I found [this](https://drupal.org/comment/7462864#comment-7462864) which is for node_view panels template. I don't know if for term_view is different.

Comment: I've never been good with the frontend related parts of Panels, so I don't have a straight answer, but if you look in the issue queue, you should be able to find the issue that added the ability to override individual panes, such as content-pane-taxonomy-term (or whatever it would actually be called).

Comment: Thanks for the comment @Letharion. Actually, my question is not related to single content panes but to the main title of the panels page. I'll check the issue queue, by the way :)

Answer (score 0):

Following the comment on the panels issue linked in the question, I managed to make the panels page override for term_view works.
This is the code added to *mytheme/**template.php***

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_page(&$vars) {
  // if this is a panel page, add template suggestions
  if($panel_page = page_manager_get_current_page()) {
    // add a generic suggestion for all panel pages
     $variables['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'page__panel';
    // add the panel page machine name to the template suggestions
    $variables['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'page__' . $panel_page['name'];
        if($panel_page['name'] == 'term_view' ) {
           $vars['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'page__term_view';
}
}
}
```

Then, inside the *mytheme/templates/* folder, I added `page--term_view.tpl.php` with my custom page title display.